# Android dashboardtile set title

Tags: android

I would like to set the title of a dashboardtile that is located in the android settings app via settingsactivity.java, does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

EDIT: sorry for short post, was in a hurry, this is what I've got so far:

```
DashboardCategory category = target.get(i);
DashboardTile tile = category.getTile(n); n = for loop with amount of tiles in a category.
String dat = tile.title.toString();
final long mobDown = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()/1048576;
CharSequence cs = dat + ": " + Long.toString(mobDown);
tile.title = cs;
```

and I get an instant nullreference exception on "dat = tile.title.toString();"

Comment: Add details and how far what yo have done.>!!

Comment: @user265889 http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i think your talking about setting toolbar text ?
if yes ....

```
//android studio

 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```